# syntax error 'from' identifier is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE dondathang
SET noigiaohang=diachi
FROM khachhang
WHERE dondathang.makhachhang=khachhang.makhachhang AND noigiaohang IS NULL;
```

I have a SQL code like above, but this is the error.

```
syntax error 'from' identifier is not valid input at this position.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM clause is irrelevant in UPDATE sintax. Please take a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

FROM Clause is not a part of UPDATE syntax, you can change the UPDATE as below

```
UPDATE dondathang
SET noigiaohang=diachi
JOIN khachhang ON dondathang.makhachhang=khachhang.makhachhang
WHERE noigiaohang IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE dondathang d JOIN
       khachhang k
       ON d.makhachhang = k.makhachhang
    SET d.noigiaohang = k.diachi
WHERE d.noigiaohang IS NULL;
```